# What's the best way to track Jitter and Packetloss

Tags: networking, monitoring, packet-analyzer, diagnostic, jitter

I need to track Jitter and Packet Loss over a MPLS line.  What's the most accurate way to capture this information without interfering with the data being sent back and forth?

Is SmokePing the best tool for the job or is there something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending how much detail you want a frequently measured MOS score may well fulfill your requirement
[MOS](http://voip.about.com/od/voipbasics/a/MOS.htm)

The link given above will suggest some tools but if you have any devices that manage VoIP (intelligent switches, routers or a VoIP PBX) then that could also measure the MOS score for you

Comment: I've found the VOIP space to be well versed in what causes poor voice quality.  MOS is interesting.  The neatest tool is http://www.telchemy.com/vqmonep.html given their use of a Markov Model with the various inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... hadn't heard of Smokeping.  I use something pretty similar to it (almost identical), though looks like [**MTR**](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) has more field categories for **Packet delivery**  and **Jitter** statistics.

[image]
<sub>(source: [googlepages.com](http://locobox.googlepages.com/mtrsavedw.jpg))</sub>

Comment: MTR is a great tool, for sure.

Comment: Looks like The Matrix

Answer (score 0):

Smokeping isn't bad, it is great to have running 24/7.

For running more detailed tests you can run iperf in udp mode with a low rate limit, that gives great stats for jitter and packet loss.